# Process Workflow Rules

Tags: workflow

Our current Work Flow creates tasks by a value in a custom field. This works fine. The issue is as each of the Work Flow process tasks are completed the value in the same field needs to change again triggering additional tasks. Id there a way to have the have the completed task change that field value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Builder and a Flow to update the custom field value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update fields as part of Workflow under certain conditions. One case where you can't do it is if the field is Read-Only. For more on how to do this, I'll refer you to [Workflow: Automating the Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_workflow_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_workflow_cheatsheet/) and another helpful sheet titled [Useful Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulWorkflowRules.meta/usefulWorkflowRules/). You'll also find additional assistance if you simply open up Help within Salesforce and look or search for Workflow.